# Auto size Button Style

Tags: wpf, xaml, autosize, wpf-style

I have this `Style`:

```
<!--Normal Button Style -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="NormalButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Effect="{DynamicResource ShadowEffect}" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="16"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Image Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Tag}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="16" Stretch="None"  Margin="0,1" />
                    <!--<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Width="Auto" Margin="0,1" Padding="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" />-->         
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And this `Button`:

```
<Button Content="Record" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" Style="{StaticResource NormalButtonStyle}" 
    Tag="Blabla.png" Height="24"/>
```

That gives me this:

[image: Button]

### The Question

For localization reasons, How to make the button with automatic size depending on the inner text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is also working.You have to remove "Width=63" from buttton only.

**Another approach**
 Here I am using stackpanel as stack panel  size based on the contents and ignores how much space is available and used TextWrapping here if there is extra space available.

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="NormalButtonStyle">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
                    <StackPanel MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Effect="{DynamicResource ShadowEffect}" >
                        <Image VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Tag}" Margin="2,0,2,0"  Width="16" Height="16" Stretch="None"/>
                        <TextBlock MaxWidth="{Binding Path=ActualWidth,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid ShowGridLines="True" Width="500">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>            
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Content="R" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinHeight="30" Padding="2,0,5,0"  Style="{StaticResource NormalButtonStyle}" Tag="btn1.jpg"/>
    <Button Content="Record" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" MinHeight="30" Padding="2,0,5,0"  Style="{StaticResource NormalButtonStyle}" Tag="btn1.jpg"/>
    <Button Content="Record here" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2" MinHeight="30" Padding="2,0,5,0"  Style="{StaticResource NormalButtonStyle}" Tag="btn1.jpg"/>
    <Button Content="Record record record record Record record record record Record record record record Record record record record Record record record record Record record record record" Grid.Row="3" MinHeight="30" Padding="2,0,5,0"  Style="{StaticResource NormalButtonStyle}" Tag="btn1.jpg"/>
    <Button Content="Record record record record Record record record record Record record record record Record record record record Record record record record Record record record record" Grid.Row="4" MinHeight="30" Padding="2,0,5,0"  Style="{StaticResource NormalButtonStyle}" Tag="btn1.jpg"/>
</Grid>
```

**Note** :

1. Use MinHeight / MinWidth / MaxHeight / MaxWidth properties in style
   designing.it helps in localization.
2. Use Auto sizing grid for Designing.

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Since I don't know who answered first, the `accept` goes to you because of the different approach.

Answer (score 3):

Simple: don't give the button a fixed width (you've set it to `63`) and make sure its `HorizontalAlignment` is not set to `Stretch` (so `Left` is fine).

You may also want to add some padding to give the text more breathing space.

Comment: Ohh, that `Width="63"` was my test code for a different approach that I forgot to remove. Ohh boy... :(